# Running rosjava node from launchfile

Tags: roslaunch, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

I try to run my rosjava node from within a launchfile. My launchfile looks like this

```
 <launch>
 <master auto="start"/>
 <node pkg="rosjava_cylinder_reasoner" type="rosjava_cylinder_reasoner"  name="cylinder_reasoner" args="de.dfki.reasoner.Service" 
 respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

The problem is that there are two generated wrapper scripts (generated from gradle) which execute the node, one is in build/install/... one is in build/scripts/. Per default roslaunch wants to execute the script in /scripts/ which results in an error because the relative path to lib (the classpath) is not set. The only solution I found so far is to delete the wrapper script from the /build/scripts/ directory. Is there any other solution to point roslaunch to the right wrapper script?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34563/running-rosjava-node-from-launchfile/) by [Markus Eich](https://answers.ros.org/users/1686/markus-eich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the following Makefile in my rosjava package.

```
SOURCES=$(shell find src/main -name *.java)
PACKAGE=<PACKAGE-NAME>

all: installed

installed: $(SOURCES)
    `rosstack find rosjava_core`/gradlew installApp
    mkdir -p bin
    ln -sf ../build/install/$(PACKAGE)/bin/$(PACKAGE) bin/execute
    chmod a+x bin/$(PACKAGE)
    touch installed rospack_nosubdirs

clean:
    `rosstack find rosjava_core`/gradlew clean
    rm -rf bin installed rospack_nosubdirs
```

To use this Makefile, you'll have to manually replace PACKAGE-NAME once. You can then use "execute" as the node type.

This solution isn't exactly pretty, but works effectively well. It also allows for rosmake/make to build the package as well. I am also interested if there are any other better solutions around.

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2